# Laplace equation on unbounded set

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

I have gotten stuck with a problem for PDEs class for a few days. I did not figure out how to start a solution for it.

**Problem:** Let $g \in C(\partial B(0, R))$, $n > 2$. Find a formula for a harmonic function $u : \mathbb{R}^n\setminus B(0, R) \to \mathbb{R}$ with $u(x) = g(x)$ on $|x| = R$, and $u(x) \to 0$ as $|x| \to \infty$. Is it unique? Is it still unique if we remove the condition $u(x) \to 0$ as $|x| \to \infty$?

I know how to find a formula for a harmonic function $u$ defined on an open bounded set, but I do not find any formula in Evans book can be applied to this situation. Plus, I have no idea how Green's functions are defined on unbounded set. Could you please help me to solve this problem?

Dan

Answer (score 1):

If you know a general formula for a solution $u$ with $u=g$ on $|x|=R$, and $u(x) \rightarrow 0$ as $|x|\rightarrow\infty$, then replace $g$ by $g-1$ and solve for $u_{g-1}$ with these properties. Then $v=u_{g-1}+1$ is a solution of Laplace's equation with $v=g$ on $|x|=R$, and $v(x)\rightarrow 1$ as $|x|\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: Actually I do not know a general formula for a solution u with u=g on |x|=R, and u(x)→0 as |x|→∞ . All I know is the formula for u: U → R where U is bounded domain. I do not know a general formula for a solution u with u=g on |x|=R, and u(x)→0 as |x|→∞, when u is a harmonic on unbounded domain. Could you explain more and tell me a general formula for a solution u with u=g on |x|=R, and u(x)→0 as |x|→∞? thank you very much

Comment: If you look at the integral formula for a solution inside the sphere, and allow the point where you are evaluating the solution to wander outside, then you have a solution outside the sphere with the outside radial limit related to the inside with a negative. This solution of Laplace's equation outside the sphere has predictable behavior at infinity. My comment was to explain why you cannot hope for uniqueness with only a condition of boundedness at infinity, and this is because constant functions are solutions of Laplace's equation.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. One more question do you mean the formula outside the ball is given by : u(x) = (|x|^2-R^2)/nα(n)R ∫   g(y) /|x-y|^n  dS(y)   where the integral is taken over ∂B(0, R)  ?

Comment: Yes, that's the one. The correct boundary values require that you negate |x|^{2}-R^{2}. Then, to get correct behavior at |x|=\infty, you'll want to subtract a couple of terms. http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Poisson_integral

Comment: Thank you very much I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I am sorry I am asking you too much, but I could not figure out how we could get the two terms ( 1/R^(n-2) * 1/nα(n)R ∫ g(y) /|x-y|^n dS(y)and  -1//|x|^(n-2) * 1/nα(n)R ∫ g(y) /|x-y|^n dS(y) ) you indicated to. Thanks

Comment: So you start with the negative the interior expression for the exterior. Then, subtract away the constant value at infinty. But that alters the value on the boundary by a constant, which can be compensated for by adding a constant multiple of 1/|x|^{n-2}, which satisfies Laplace's equation, vanishes at infinity, and is a constant on the sphere. Now you have a solution in the exterior which vanishes at infinity and equals the required values on the sphere.